# What is causing this LinearLayout casting error?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm learning Kotlin after exclusively working in Java previously, and I've run into a bit of a confusing error that I can't seem to fix.

I tried to implement a `RecyclerView`, and every effort I've made has failed. I even copy\pasted the code from the [developer page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) to see what I am doing wrong, only to run into the same issue. It's been hours at this point and I'm stumped.

***Why am I getting this error from code that is directly from the dev page\how do I fix it?***

***MyAdapter.kt***

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MyAdapter(private val myDataset: Array<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder.
    // Each data item is just a string in this case that is shown in a TextView.
    class MyViewHolder(val textView: TextView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView)

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                    viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {
        // create a new view
        val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false) as TextView
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        return MyViewHolder(textView)
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.textView.text = myDataset[position]
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun getItemCount() = myDataset.size
}
```

***Error from logcat***

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root layout of `R.layout.my_text_view` is probably a `LinearLayout` (you should post the layout file as well). You are inflating the layout and casting the root view to a `TextView`.

You should inflate the layout with

```
val rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false)
```

then get a reference to the `TextView` inside this layout with something like

```
val textView = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.[your-textview-id])
```

Comment: Yup, that was it! Thanks!